# Does such a family of sets exist?

Tags: set-theory

Here is a question on set theory:

Does there exist a family $S$ of closed discs in $\mathbb{R^2}$ having positive radii such that each of these discs has at most one point in common and $\mathbb{R^2}- {\cup D}$ is countable.

I have no idea how to approach this question.

Please tell me a hint how to start this one

Comment: Are the disks required to have *positive* radii? Because if zero-radius disks (each of which is a point) are allowed, this problem seems very easy.

Comment: @JohnHughes: Yes, all disc have positive radii, I will update that in the question.

Comment: With the "at most one" condition, you mean that $\bigcap_{D\in S}D$ is either empty or a singleton? Or do you mean that for every $D_1\ne D_2$, the set $D_1\cap D_2$ is either empty or a singleton?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: I mean the second case, for every $D_1 \ne D_2$ either the intersection is empty or singleton

Comment: By countable, you mean that $|S|=|\mathbb{N}|$ or $|S|\le |\mathbb{N}|$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a well known theorem (of Sierpiński I believe) that the real line does not admit a nontrivial partition into countably many closed sets; see my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3800398/closed-a-b%e2%8a%86-mathbbr-is-not-a-countable-union-of-%e2%89%a52-disjoint-closed-inter).

Now assume for a contradiction that the plane is the union of a (necessarily countable) collection of closed discs (of positive radius) with disjoint interiors, plus countably many single points.

Let $L$ be a line in the plane which does not pass through any of the countably many points where two of those closed discs touch. The intersection of each of the given discs with $L$ is either a closed interval or a single point. Thus $L$ is the union of a countable disjoint collection of closed intervals and singletons, contradicting the theorem mentioned above.

**Remark.** If $S$ is a family of closed discs of positive radius with disjoint interiors in $\mathbb R^2$, then $\mathbb R^2\setminus\bigcup S$ is an uncountable $G_\delta$ set, so it has cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$.