# Prove that $[0,1]$ is not a disjoint union of a countable family of closed sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification, baire-category

This proof is probably too long, please don't downvote this. I'm just leaving it here in case somebody wants to actually verify its validity for me. I didn't use a hint in the book and decided to prove it my own way.

Outline of the proof:

- After trying to cover $[0,1]$ with 2 disjoint closed sets A and B, show that there will remain some open interval $(c_{0}, c_{1}) \in [0,1]$ that has to be covered, where $c_{0} \in A$ or $B$, $c_{1} \in A$ or $B$.
- Use some closed set to try cover this interval and obtain 2 intervals $(c_{00}, c_{01}), (c_{10}, c_{11})$ yet to cover, where all endpoints belong to closed sets (endpoints are not necessarily infs/sups of those closed sets, just points belonging to them).
- Repeat this process infinitely, proving that trying to cover each of $n$ intervals will create at least $2n$ yet uncovered open intervals (taking into account that total length of all open intervals has to approach 0).
- Prove that there will be an uncountable number of points left not belonging to any of the above closed sets after the above process, and name this set $N$. Name set of all endpoints of closed sets (i.e. $c_{0}, c_{10}$...) $E$.
- To make proving that $N$ is not a union of a countable number of closed sets easier, define a metric space $S$ with Euclidian metric which consists of a) set $N^\prime$ which contains same points as $N \in \mathbb{R}$, b) set $E^\prime$ which contains same points as $E \in \mathbb{R}$. Proceed to prove this space is complete, then assume $N^\prime$ is a union of a countable number of closed sets, and then use Baire Category Theorem to derive a contradiction, henceforth negating the assumption.
- Prove that $N^\prime$ not being a union of a countable number of closed sets in $S$ implies that $N$ is not a union of a countable number of closed sets in $\mathbb{R}$, which would imply that $[0,1]$ is not a union of a countable number of disjoint closed sets.

Proof:

1. Every nonempty bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$ has inf/sup, and that inf/sup belongs to the subset if it is closed (if it's isolated from the set then it is a min/max of the set and is an isolated point of the set, if it's not isolated from the set then it's a limit point thus belongs to it).
2. Take a closed set $A \subset \mathbb{R} \mid A \cap [0,1] \neq \emptyset$. Take a random point $x \in ([0,1] \setminus A), x \notin \{0,1\} \implies \exists \epsilon > 0 \mid B_{\epsilon}(x) \in ([0,1] \setminus A)$, since if not, A will not be a closed set. Take $(c_{0}, c_{1}) \subset [0,1] \mid c_{0} = \max(\sup(A \cap [0,x)),0), c_{1} = \min(\inf(A \cap (x,1]), 1)$. If $c_{0} \notin A$ or $c_{1} \notin A$, then $c_{0} = 0$ or $c_{1} = 1$, so attempting to cover $[0, c_{1})$ or $(c_{0}, 1]$ with another closed set B will yield an open interval of form $(c_{0}, c_{1})$. Next:
3. Take arbitrary closed set $C_{0} \cap (c_{0},c_{1}) \neq \emptyset $. $c_{0},c_{1}$ are not limit points of $C_{0}$ as $c_{0},c_{1} \notin C_{0}$ since they belong to $B$ and $A$, also $C_{0} \cap (c_{0},c_{1})$ is bounded. Thus $\exists c_{01}, c_{10} \in C_{0} | c_{0} < \inf(C_{0} \cap (c_{0},c_{1}))=c_{01} \in C_{0} \leq \sup(C_{0} \cap (c_{0},c_{1}))=c_{10} \in C_{1} < c_{1}$. Denote $c_{0}$ as $c_{00}$ and $c_{1}$ as $c_{11}$, so an open set $(c_{00}, c_{01}) \cup (c_{10}, c_{11})$ is still not covered, and proceed further in this fashion.
4. In this proof only, we will denote $\overline{d_{\overline{m1}}...d_{\overline{mn}}}$ as $d_{m1}...d_{mn}$, a sequence of 0s and 1s, where m (first sub-subscript) denotes ordinal number of open interval in a union $O^\prime_{n}$ and second sub-subscript ranges from 1 to n where n is a step at which we are trying to cover all open sets. Let $ O_{d_{m1}...d_{m(n-1)}} = (c_{d_{m1}...d_{m(n-1)}0}, c_{d_{m1}...d_{m(n-1)}1}) $ and $O^\prime_{n-1} = \bigcup\limits_{m=1; \{d_{m1}...d_{m(n-1)}:1 \leq k \leq n, d_{mk} \in \{0,1\}\}}^{2^{n-1}} O_{d_{m1}...d_{m(n-1)}}$. Since at $n$-th step we have to cover $2^{n-1}$ open intervals, we can take a union of disjoint closed sets $C^\prime_{n-1} = \bigcup\limits_{m=1; \{d_{m1}...d_{m(n-1)}:1 \leq k \leq n-1, d_{mk} \in \{0,1\}\}}^{2^{n-1}} C_{d_{m1}...d_{m(n-1)}}$ and take its intersection with open set $O^\prime_{n-1}$ so that $C_{d_{m1}...d_{m(n-1)}} \cap O_{d_{m1}...d_{m(n-1)}} \neq \emptyset$. This implies $\forall m, 1 \leq m \leq 2^{n-1}, \hspace{0.1cm} \exists c_{d_{m1}...d_{m(n-1)}01} = \inf(O_{d_{m1}...d_{m(n-1)}} \cap C^\prime_{n-1}) $ and $\exists c_{d_{m1}...d_{m(n-1)}10} = \sup(O_{d_{m1}...d_{m(n-1)}} \cap C^\prime_{n-1}) \mid (c_{d_{m1}...d_{m(n-1)}00},c_{d_{m1}...d_{m(n-1)}01}) \cup (c_{d_{m1}...d_{m(n-1)}10},c_{d_{m1}...d_{m(n-1)}11}) \subset (O_{d_{m1}...d_{m(n-1)}} \setminus C^\prime_{n-1}) $. $(c_{d_{m1}...d_{m(n-1)}00},c_{d_{m1}...d_{m(n-1)}01}) = (c_{d_{k1}...d_{k(n-1)}d_{kn}0},c_{d_{k1}...d_{k(n-1)}d_{kn}1}) = O_{d_{k1}...d_{k(n-1)}d_{kn}} \subset O^\prime_n$. Denote $O = \bigcup\limits_{m=0}^{\infty} O^\prime_{m}$, $C = \bigcup\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} C^\prime_{n}$, $E = \{c_{d_{m1}...d_{mn}d_{mn}d_{mn}...}: k \in \mathbb{N}, d_{mk} \in \{0,1\}\}$. Also please note that for any endpoint in $E$ with finite subscript, such as $c_{d_{m1}d_{m2}...d_{mn}}$, $c_{d_{m1}d_{m2}...d_{mn}} = c_{d_{m1}d_{m2}...d_{mn}d_{mn}d_{mn}...}$, i.e. its finite subscript is equivalent to its infinite subscript which has last digit of its finite subscript repeating infinitely.
5. Since closed sets must cover entire $[0,1], \lim_{n \to +\infty} \sum\limits_{m=1;\{d_{m1}...d_{m(n-1)}: d_{mk} \in \{0,1\}, 1 \leq k \leq n-1\}}^{2^{n-1}} |c_{d_{m1}...d_{m(n-1)}1}-c_{d_{m1}...d_{m(n-1)}0}| = 0$. The number of closed sets will be countable (can get an injection to $\mathbb{Q} \subset [0,1]$:  $f(m,n)=(2m-1)/2^n$ for $m$-th closed set inserted at $n$-th step, $2m-1<2^n$).
6. This infinite union of disjoint closed sets will not cover the entire $[0,1]$. Take an intersection of nested open intervals $\bigcap\limits_{n=1; d_{q_{k}k} \in \{0,1\}, 1 \leq k \leq n}^{\infty} O_{d_{q_{1}1}...d_{q_{n}n}} \mid O_{d_{q_{1}1}...d_{q_{n-1}(n-1)}d_{q_{n}n}} \subset O_{d_{q_{1}1}...d_{q_{n-1}(n-1)}}$ and $\forall n_{1} \in \mathbb{N} \hspace{0.1cm} \exists n_{2} \in \mathbb{N}, n_{2} > n_{1} \mid d_{q_{n_{2}}n_{2}}=1-d_{q_{n_{1}}n_{1}}$ and take a sequence of points $(o_{d_{q_{1}1}...d_{q_{n}n}}), o_{d_{q_{1}1}...d_{q_{n}n}} \in O_{d_{q_{1}1}...d_{q_{n-1}n-1}}$. $(o_{d_{q_{1}1}...d_{q_{n}n}}) \rightarrow L \notin C$. Proof: assume $L \in (C \setminus E) \implies \exists e_{1}, e_{2} \in E \mid L \in (e_{1}, e_{2})$, $[e_{1}, e_{2}] \subset C \implies \exists \epsilon > 0 \mid B_{\epsilon}(L) \cap O = \emptyset \implies L \notin (C \setminus E) $. Assume $L=c_{d_{m_{1}1}...d_{m_{n}n}d_{m_{n+1}(n+1)}...} \in E \implies \exists N \in \mathbb{N} \mid \forall n,k \geq N, d_{m_{k}k}=d_{m_{n}n}$. Take a sequence $(o_{d_{m_{1}1}...d_{m_{n}n}})$, $o_{d_{m_{1}1}...d_{m_{n}n}} \in O_{d_{m_{1}1}...d_{m_{n-1}n-1}}$, $O_{m}=(O \supset O_{d_{m_{1}1}} \supset O_{d_{m_{1}1}d_{m_{2}2}} \supset ... \supset O_{d_{m_{1}1}...d_{m_{N-1}(N-1)}d_{m_{N}N}d_{m_{N+1}N}}...)$. $\exists N^\prime \geq N \mid d_{q_{N^\prime}N^\prime} = 1-d_{m_{N^\prime}N^\prime} \implies \exists \epsilon > 0 \mid \forall N^{\prime\prime} > N^\prime$, $|o_{d_{q_{1}1}...d_{q_{N^{\prime\prime}}N^{\prime\prime}}}-o_{d_{m_{1}1}...d_{m_{N^{\prime\prime}}N^{\prime\prime}}}| > \epsilon$ since $O_{d_{q_{1}1}...d_{q_{N^{\prime\prime}-1}N^{\prime\prime}-1}} \cap O_{d_{m_{1}1}...d_{m_{N^{\prime\prime}-1}N^{\prime\prime}-1}} = \emptyset$. For the above $\epsilon/2$ there exist $N_{q} \in \mathbb{N} \mid \forall n \geq N_{q}$, $ |o_{q_{1}1q_{2}2...q_{n}n}-L| < \epsilon/2$, $N_{m} \in \mathbb{N} \mid \forall n \geq N_{m}$, $ |o_{m_{1}1m_{2}2...m_{n}n}-L| < \epsilon/2$. This implies $\exists M = max(N^{\prime\prime}, N_{q}, N_{m}) \mid \forall n \geq M$, $\epsilon < |o_{m_{1}1...m_{M}M}-o_{q_{1}1...q_{M}M}| = |o_{m_{1}1...m_{M}M}-L+L-o_{q_{1}1...q_{M}M}| \leq |o_{m_{1}1...m_{M}M}-L|+|L-o_{q_{1}1...q_{M}M}| < \epsilon/2+\epsilon/2 = \epsilon$ which is a contradiction $\implies L \notin (E \cup (C \setminus E)) \implies L \notin C$. Also, we can similarly prove that $L = \bigcap\limits_{n=1; d_{q_{k}k} \in \{0,1\}, 1 \leq k \leq n}^{\infty} O_{d_{q_{1}1}...d_{q_{n}n}} \mid O_{d_{q_{1}1}...d_{q_{n-1}(n-1)}d_{q_{n}n}} \subset O_{d_{q_{1}1}...d_{q_{n-1}(n-1)}}$ by assuming it doesn't belong to this intersection which will imply that there exists some $\epsilon > 0$ and some $N \in \mathbb{N} \mid \forall n \geq N, |o_{q_{1}1...q_{n}n}-L| > \epsilon$.
7. Denote $ N = \bigcup\limits_{\{d_{m1}d_{m2}...: d_{mk} \in \{0,1\}\}} (\bigcap\limits_{n=1; d_{mk} \in \{0,1\}, 1 \leq k \leq n}^{\infty} O_{d_{m1}...d_{mn}} \mid \forall t \in \mathbb{N} \hspace{0.1cm} \exists q \in \mathbb{N}, q > t \mid d_{mq}=1-d_{mt}) = \{o_{d_{m1}d_{m2}...}: \forall t \in \mathbb{N} \hspace{0.1cm} \exists q \in \mathbb{N}, q > t \mid d_{mq}=1-d_{mt}\}$ (by the above proof of intersection of nested open intervals being non-empty and converging to a point L in the intersection). This union amounts to a union of uncountably infinite number of points with each point having as subscript an infinite sequence consisting of 2 subsequences of 0's and 1's. Since $\forall L \in N, L \notin E \implies N \cap E = \emptyset$. We have to prove $N$ is not a countable union of disjoint closed sets. Proof:

   - Define a metric space $S = (N \cup E, d)$, $d$ is the Euclidian metric, $N \cap E = \emptyset$. It is complete which we prove next. $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, O_{d_{m1}d_{m2}...d_{mn}} = (c_{d_{m1}d_{m2}...d_{mn}0}, c_{d_{m1}d_{m2}...d_{mn}1}) \implies N \cup E = (\bigcup\limits_{\{d_{m1}d_{m2}...: d_{mk} \in \{0,1\}\}} (\bigcap\limits_{n=1; d_{mk} \in \{0,1\}, 1 \leq k \leq n}^{\infty} (c_{d_{m1}d_{m2}...d_{mn}0}, c_{d_{m1}d_{m2}...d_{mn}1}) \mid \forall t \in \mathbb{N} \hspace{0.1cm} \exists q \in \mathbb{N}, q > t \mid d_{mq}=1-d_{mt})) \cup \{c_{d_{m1}d_{m2}d_{m3}...d_{mn}d_{mn}d_{mn}...}: k \in \mathbb{N}, d_{mk} \in \{0,1\}\} = (\bigcup\limits_{\{d_{m1}d_{m2}...: d_{mk} \in \{0,1\}\}} (\bigcap\limits_{n=1; d_{mk} \in \{0,1\}, 1 \leq k \leq n}^{\infty} [c_{d_{m1}d_{m2}...d_{mn}0}, c_{d_{m1}d_{m2}...d_{mn}1}] \mid \forall t \in \mathbb{N} \hspace{0.1cm} \exists q \in \mathbb{N}, q > t \mid d_{mq}=1-d_{mt})) = (\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (\bigcup\limits_{d_{mk} \in \{0,1\}, 1 \leq k \leq n} [c_{d_{m1}d_{m2}...d_{mn}0}, c_{d_{m1}d_{m2}...d_{mn}1}])$. It is closed since finite union of closed sets is closed, and intersection of an arbitrary number of closed sets is closed. Since $S$ is closed it is complete under the same Euclidian metric.
   - $N \in \mathbb{R}$ is defined as $N = \bigcap\limits_{n=1;\{d_{mk}: 1 \leq k \leq n, d_{mk} \in \{0,1\}\}}^{\infty} O_{d_{m1}d_{m2}...d_{mn}} = \bigcap\limits_{m=1}^{\infty} O_{m}^{\prime}$. Take some $m \in \mathbb{N}$, $O_{m}^{\prime}$ open in $\mathbb{R} \implies \forall x \in ((N \cup E) \cap O_{m}^{\prime}) \hspace{0.05cm} \exists \epsilon > 0 \mid B_{\epsilon}(x) \subset O_{m}^{\prime} \implies \forall y \in B_{\epsilon}(x), y \in (N \cup E)$ or $y \in (O_{m}^{\prime} \setminus (N \cup E)) \implies$ because $S$ consists of points in $N \cup E$, $N_{m}^{\prime} = (O_{m}^{\prime} \cap (N \cup E))$ is open in $S$. If $N \in \mathbb{R}, N=\bigcap\limits_{m=1}^{\infty} O_{m}^{\prime}=\bigcap\limits_{m=1}^{\infty} (O_{m}^{\prime} \cap (N \cup E))=\bigcap\limits_{m=1}^{\infty} N_{m}^{\prime}= N^{\prime}$, so $N^\prime$ (denoted as $N^{\prime}$ to indicate it refers to $S$) can be expressed as intersection of a countable number of open sets in $S$. Denote $E^{\prime}$ to indicate it refers to $S$. Assume $N^{\prime} = \bigcup\limits_{m=1}^{\infty} T_{m}, T_{m}$ closed $\implies (N^{\prime})^\complement = E^{\prime} = (\bigcup\limits_{m=1}^{\infty} T_{m})^\complement = \bigcap\limits_{m=1}^{\infty} E_{m}^{\prime}, \forall m \in \mathbb{N}, E_{m}^{\prime}$ open. Both $N$ and $E$ are dense in $S$ since $\forall n \in N$ and $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists e \in E \mid e \in B_{\epsilon}(n) \implies$ since space $S$ is complete, $\overline{E} = (N \cup E) \implies \forall m \in \mathbb{N}, E_{m}^{\prime}$ is dense in $S$. Similarly, $\forall e \in E$ and $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists n \in N \mid n \in B_{\epsilon}(e) \implies$ since space $S$ is complete, $\overline{N} = (E \cup N) \implies \forall m \in \mathbb{N}, N_{m}^{\prime}$ is dense in $S$. Therefore we have $E^{\prime} \cap N^{\prime} = (\bigcap\limits_{m=1}^{\infty} E_{m}^{\prime}) \cap (\bigcap\limits_{m=1}^{\infty} N_{m}^{\prime}) = \emptyset$, but by Baire Category Theorem, countable intersection of dense open sets is a proper subset of a complete metric space. So $N^{\prime}$ is not a union of a countable number of closed sets in $S$. Therefore $N$ is not a union of a countable number of closed sets in $\mathbb{R}$. Proof: assume $N = \bigcup\limits_{m=1}^{\infty} N_{m}, \forall m \in \mathbb{N} N_{m}$ closed. Then every $N_{m} \subset N \implies N_{m} \subset N^{\prime}$ in $S$. Assume $N_{m}^{\prime}$ is not closed in $S$, then $\exists (n_{k}) \rightarrow L \notin N_{m}^{\prime} \implies$ since $N_{m}$ and $N_{m}^{\prime}$ consist of the same elements, $(n_{k}) \rightarrow L \notin N_{m} \implies N_{m}$ is not closed which is a contradiction. Hence $N_{m}^{\prime}$ is closed in $S$ and $N^{\prime} = \bigcup\limits_{m=1}^{\infty} N_{m}^{\prime}$ is a union of a countable number of closed sets in $S$ which contradicts our proof above. Therefore the assumption is wrong and $N$ cannot be expressed as a union of a countable number of closed sets in $\mathbb{R}$. Therefore $N \cup C \cup B \cup A \neq [0,1]$ and $[0,1]$ is not a countable union of disjoint closed sets.

Comment: Uhh.... "here is my proof is it correct" kind of questions are generally not allowed and as you have noted your proof is very very long. However, if there is a specific part in the proof that you are unsure of we would be glad to help :).

Comment: Your post is quite complicated. In general one can use Sierpinski's theorem on continua

Comment: @Jakobian Yes. I'm giving the OP a reference (for general case too)

Comment: Spaces which can't be non-trivially partitioned into countable amount of disjoint closed sets are called $\sigma$-connected by some authors (e.g. Nadler). Sierpiński's theorem on continua says that all continua are $\sigma$-connected. One can summarize the statement you're proving by "$[0, 1]$ is $\sigma$-connected".

Comment: To get $\{$ and $\}$ in MathJax type `\{` and `\}` (you are typing `\\{` and `\\}`)

Comment: @bobeyt6 I added the outline of the proof to help understand the process. Will refrain from check requests in the future :)

Comment: @Jakobian thanks, will look into this

Comment: @jjagmath thanks a lot!!

Comment: why are you not done after bullet point $4$? If you prove that any way you try to cover the interval with closed sets leaves uncountably many points outside the cover, then no countable cover exists, no?

Comment: @SomeCallMeTim I have to prove that points left after the covering process can't be covered with a countable number of (disjoint) closed sets either? Otherwise we could cover those points with a countable number of (disjoint) closed sets (my proof, I believe, shows they can't be covered with any countable union of closed sets), and then cover the rest with another countably infinite number of disjoint closed sets as described in covering process, which in total would amount to whole [0,1] being covered with countable number of disjoint closed sets.

Comment: @SomeCallMeTim points left over will be limits of Cauchy sequences.

Comment: For a shorter proof, see the answer to this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3800398/closed-a-b%e2%8a%86-mathbbr-is-not-a-countable-union-of-%e2%89%a52-disjoint-closed-inter

Comment: @StanislavVeklenko Can you point at which part of your proof you are having trouble with? What you could do is keep the outline, which would serve as context, and then ask about a specific step afterwards. As written, this is too long for a proof verification question, and will likely be closed as too broad.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber I don't think I necessarily have trouble with any part of the proof, it seems to work from my point of view, that's why I posted it whole. Maybe only bullet points 5 and 6 I am a little unsure of.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber should I edit the question then? Delete proof and ask about bullet points 5/6?

Comment: @StanislavVeklenko sure, as long as you have specific questions about specific parts, rather than just a general "is this right" about a wall of text

Comment: @AlexanderGruber on second thought I think you can close this question.